# Opening new browser window with Blazor application

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a problem opening a new window with the Blazor application and "post" parameters. Of course, the problem will probably also apply to "IFrame", that's why I think it's worth "leaning over" the subject.

for example:

```
    <form target="_blank" method="post" action="https://localhost:44373/counter">
      <input type="hidden" value="Test OK" />
      <button type="submit">Post</span></button>
    </form>
    <a href="https://localhost:44373/counter/GetOk" target="_blank">Get</a>
```

As you can see I have 2 actions that open a slightly modified code (template) of the Blazor application. When I open the application as "GET" everything is ok, but when I do it as "POST" I get this error.

> VM18289:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://localhost/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
>   counter:1 POST https://localhost:44373/counter 400
>   Navigated to https://localhost:44373/counter
>   Navigated to chrome-error://chromewebdata/

There is a way to work around this or fix it. Please treat this as an experiment, it is one of the problems that arises during learning. :)

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/ – This isn’t really related to Blazor though.